How do you tail logs by keeping state in a k8s cluster?
I am referring to tail - keep_state.
However, I am running fluent-bit in a container on k8s pod. Containers and pods are ephemeral by nature, so how can I store the state of tail input plugin so that it is retained even though pod gets restarted or even a k8s node gets changed for any reason.
A small code snippet for configuring this would be immensely helpful.
